# How to properly use bin_package in Yocto

Tags: embedded, yocto, bitbake

Good day,

I am trying to unpack the files from a .tar.gz archive into my bitbake generated image.

Basically just copy some files from the archive **to** usr/lib/fonts

File structure is like so:

```
├── deploy-executable
│   └── usr
│       └── lib
│           └── fonts
│               ├── LiberationMono-BoldItalic.ttf
│               ├── LiberationMono-Bold.ttf
│               ├── LiberationMono-Italic.ttf
│               ├── LiberationMono-Regular.ttf
│               ├── LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf
....
```

This goes inside an archive called **deploy-executable-0.1.tar.gz**

Now my **deploy-executable_0.1.bb** file looks like  this:

```
SUMMARY = "Recipe for populating with bin_package"
DESCRIPTION ="This recipe uses bin_package to add some demo files to an image"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SRC_URI = "file://${BP}.tar.gz"

inherit bin_package
```

(I have followed the instructions from this post: https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2015-December/027681.html)

The problem is that I keep getting the following error:

`ERROR: deploy-executable-0.1-r0 do_install: bin_package has nothing to install. Be sure the SRC_URI unpacks into S.`

Can anyone help me?
Let me know if you need more information. I will be happy to provide.

Comment: You need to set `S` (source directory) accordingly because the default is `${WORKDIR}/${BP}` and in your case, it's probably empty/non-existing.

Comment: thank you @qschulz for your answer. While adding S = "${WORKDIR}" the bitbake operation was stuck in a loop which lasted 36 hours before I decided it to cancel it.

Meanwhile I have found the problem which was that the file INSIDE my **deploy-executable-0.1.tar.gz** had the name **deploy-executable** . I have corrected the name to **deploy-executable-0.1** and repacked the .tar.gz . 

I had a succesful build. Thank you again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution:

Add a `subdir` parameter after the filepath (and leave `${S}` alone) to your tarball to get it unpack to the right location.

E.G.

```
SRC_URI = "file://${BP}.tar.gz;subdir=${BP}"
```

#### Explanation:

According to [bitbake docs](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html#term-SRC_URI)

> subdir : Places the file (or extracts its contents) into the specified subdirectory. This option is useful for unusual tarballs or other archives that do not have their files already in a subdirectory within the archive.

So when your tarball gets extracted and unpacked, you can specify that it should go into `${BP}` (relative to `${WORKDIR}`) which is what `do_package` & co. expect.

Note that this is also called out in the [`bin_package.bbclass`](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/classes/bin_package.bbclass#L11-L18) recipe class file itself (though for a slightly different application):

```
# Note:
# The "subdir" parameter in the SRC_URI is useful when the input package
# is rpm, ipk, deb and so on, for example:
#
# SRC_URI = "http://example.com/foo-1.0-r1.i586.rpm;subdir=foo-1.0"
#
# Then the files would be unpacked to ${WORKDIR}/foo-1.0, otherwise
# they would be in ${WORKDIR}.
```

I ran into issues simply doing `${S} = ${WORKDIR}` because I had some leftover artifacts in my working directory from a recipe from *before* I made it a `bin_package`. The leftover `sysroot_*` artifacts wreaked havoc on `do_package_shlibs`... Figured it was better to just unpack the archive where it was expected to go instead of mucking with changing `${S}` for a bit of robustness.